# Confused with nodejs exports while value is defined but throw error as undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I got real confused with exports, the following code keep getting error with (i am new to nodejs)

```
TEST OUT [object Object]
called me
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mailer' of undefined
    at Function.exports.test (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PS/server/mail.js:13:28)
```

But i have required the mailer and when i try to console.log it out it's not undefined as well? Any one can help?

`require('./mail')(app, config);` (where i inject the app and config)

```
var mailer = require('express-mailer');

var exports = module.exports = function(app, config) {
};

exports.test = function(app, config) {
  console.log('TEST OUT ' + mailer)
  console.log("called me");
  mailer.extend(app, config.mailer);

  app.mailer.send('email.ejs', {
    to: 'btest@test.com', // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field.  
    subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED. 
    data : 'repalce me mate'
    // otherProperty: 'Other Property' // All additional properties are also passed to the template as local variables. 
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error 
      console.log(err);
      res.send('There was an error sending the email');
      return;
    }
    console.log("SEND")
    // res.send('Email Sent');
  });
};
```

FIX

```
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
var _app;
var _config;

var exports = module.exports = function(app, config) {
    _app = app;
    _config = config;
};

exports.test = function() {
  mailer.extend(_app, _config.mailer);

  app.mailer.send('email.ejs', {
    to: 'btest@test.com', // REQUIRED. This can be a comma delimited string just like a normal email to field.  
    subject: 'Test Email', // REQUIRED. 
    data : 'repalce me mate'
    // otherProperty: 'Other Property' // All additional properties are also passed to the template as local variables. 
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error 
      console.log(err);
      res.send('There was an error sending the email');
      return;
    }
    console.log("SEND")
    // res.send('Email Sent');
  });
};
```

Comment: Apparently the error in this line `mailer.extend(app, config.mailer);`. Are you sure that the `config` object has property `mailer`? Try `console.log(config)`.

Comment: Thanks mate i have fixed, can you see if there is better solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could receive in your mail file an `app` and a `config`, and finally export an object containing a method called `test`, so that in your `test` method, `app` and `config` variables will be available.

```
'use strict';

var mailer = require('express-mailer');

module.exports = function(app, config) {
  // some code ..

  return {
    test: function() {
      var message = {
        to: 'btest@test.com',
        subject: 'Test Email',
        data: 'replace me mate'
      };

      mailer.extend(app, config.mailer);
      app.mailer.send('email.ejs', message, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }

        console.log('message was sent successfully');
      });
    }
  };
}
```

And when you consume it, you could do something like:

```
var mailer = require('./mail.')(app, config);
mailer.test();
```